# Как сделать подложку для активной ссылки?

Tags: css

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста. Нужно сделать так, как на картинке, чтобы при наведении на ссылку, она выделялась вот такой красной лентой:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наставлю в правильном направлении - z-index вам в помощь.
[Пример](http://css-tricks.com/examples/RoundOutTabs/) как накладываются подложки из форменных элементов